# How to force JSON request body to contain some specific parameter in ASP.NET Web API 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

In our project, there is a POST method which take a JSON request body like this:

```
{
"UserId": string,
"Username": string,
"Email": string
}
```

It's ok if "Email" is null but we want it to always present in the request body.

So this is OK:

```
{
"UserId": "u12324",
"Username": "tmpUser",
"Email": null
}
```

but this is not:

```
{
"UserId": "u12324",
"Username": "tmpUser"
}
```

Do you have any ideas? Is it even possible?

Comment: Your premise is somewhat incorrect, since most serializers by default will treat a null value as non-existent upon deserialization.  Most will of course allow you to override this, but your need is still unclear.

If using JSON.Net, you could write a custom JsonConverter that inspects the raw string for the presence of your property and then throw an error if it isn't present.

Answer (score 3):

You are using [asp.net-web-api](/questions/tagged/asp.net-web-api), which uses [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) as its underlying JSON serializer, according to [JSON and XML Serialization in ASP.NET Web API](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization).  This serializer allows you to specify that a given property must be present (and optionally non-null) with the [`JsonPropertyAttribute.Required`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyRequired.htm) attribute setting, which has [4 values](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Required.htm):

> ```
> Default      The property is not required. The default state.
> AllowNull    The property must be defined in JSON but can be a null value.
> Always       The property must be defined in JSON and cannot be a null value. 
> DisallowNull The property is not required but it cannot be a null value.
> ```

The following class makes use of these attributes:

```
public class EmailData
{
    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)] // Must be present and non-null
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)] // Must be present and non-null
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(Required = Required.AllowNull)] // Must be present but can be null
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Note that setting `[JsonProperty(Required = Required.Always)]` will cause an exception to be thrown during *serialization* if the property value is null.

Answer (score -1):

Try to pass all parameters in a object

Example

```
[HttpPost]
        public bool Create(DoSomething model)
        {
            return true
        }



public class DoSomething 
    {
        public int UserId{ get; set; }
        public string UserName{ get; set; }
        public string Email{ get; set; }
    }
```